# Question about power good connections

Tags: power, linear-regulator

I have a question about power good connections.

In my circuit design I'm using a LDO linear regulator (TPS79401,) an USB 3.0 controller (TUSB7320) and a Raspberry Compute Module 4. I have seen on a TI forum one schematic where the GRST pin was connected to RUN_PG by a resistor, but the GRST pin of TUSB7320 datasheet says that if this pin is high, the device doesn't work.

Furthermore, TI recommends this: "It is highly recommended that the GRST# input be connected to a power good output from a power supply", and on their schematics and recommended design they connect PG of power supply TPS74401 (I'm using 79401 because there is not stock and are almost the same) to GRST.

How should I connect these pins? GRST_TUSB7320 to PG_TPS79401? GRST_TUSB7320 to Rasp_RUN_PG? All of them connected by the same wire?

PG pin TPS79401

[image: TPS74901]

TUSB7320 GRST

[image: TUSB7320]

Raspberry Compute Module 4

[image: Raspberry Compute Module 4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have mixed something up. Read section 9.1.1 Power-UpSequence in the TUSB73x0 datasheet.The reset is "asserted" (activated) by pulling it low. So by tying it to a PG pin of a regulator (which goes high when all is good) the reset pin will be deasserted (deactivated) as it should. T

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right. Asserted doesn't want to say High, is it? My mistake, I understood "low impedance state" as a 0, not as a 1. Anyway, if all the pg's were connected between them, what could it happen? The fastest PG would command the others?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually the slowest to be OK would release the PG line to the "good state". PGs are usually only outputs that can only sink current. Wiring this to the IO pin run_pg would also reset the RPi if the TPS isn't up. Maybe ok?

Comment: But, if the time of power on of TPS is more than RPi time, RPi would restart, maybe is better that there is not dependences between TPS and RPi (TPS only provides power to TUSB7320)?

Comment: A good conclusion! Dont forget the pullup on the PG, it can be to the TPS own output voltage. Glhf

Comment: Thank you so much!